# AWS nodejs SDK v3 not applying forcePathStyle / endpoint?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have a TS express application that I wanted to run LocalStack with for testing / e2e purposes. (my actual app will call aws s3).

I have localstack set up properly, and correctly adding files and what not:

> aws s3api put-object --endpoint http://localhost:4566 --key mykey --body myfile.json --bucket mybucket

will correctly place the file and what not.

For my Nodejs app, I have the client set up like so:

```
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
client = new S3Client({'us-east-1', endpoint: 'http://localhost:4566', forcePathStyle: true, disableHostPrefix:true}); //
```

and then a putobject like so:

```
 const command = new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: 'mybucket',
    Key: entryPath,
    ContentType: 'application/json',
    Body: JSON.stringify(data),
  });

client.send(command)
```

for some reason, the command fails with a ECONNREFUSED ::1:4566 ...which is due to the fact (at least according to the logs) s3client is attempting to call: mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/[MYKEY]

so it seems its neither adhering to `endpoint` nor the `forcedStyle` args